# Array type mismatch

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have my listening history from Spotify on an Excel sheet. I'd like to extract all unique artists from that list and write them in a different column in the same Excel sheet.

```vb
Sub CountUniqueValues()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Spotify_Analysis_XYZ.xlsm")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim UniqueArtists As Variant
    UniqueArtists = Evaluate("Unique(" & "B2:B" & LastRow & ",TRUE,FALSE)")
    ws1.Cells("2:40000", 8) = UniqueArtists
    
End Sub
```

Where all artists are stored in column B.

I get a type mismatch.

Comment: `ws1` Isn't defined. You need to change it to `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` or `Dim ws As Worksheet` to `Dim ws1 As Worksheet`

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2?

Comment: Make sure you specify on which sheet the evaluate should use: `ws1.Evaluate(....`

Comment: [MS Office help: Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)

Comment: While it’s good to understand VBA, why aren’t you just using UNIQUE() in a spreadsheet function (since you are using an Excel version where the function exists). =UNIQUE(B:B,TRUE,FALSE) in whatever cell you want to be the top of the results column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to make it work.  Your last line was not a range.

```
Sub CountUniqueValues()

Dim t As Long

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Spotify_Analysis_XYZ.xlsm")

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim UniqueArtists As Variant
UniqueArtists = Evaluate("Unique(Sheet1!B2:B" & LastRow & ",false,FALSE)")
t = UBound(UniqueArtists) - 1
ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 8), ws1.Cells(2 + t, 8)) = UniqueArtists


End Sub
```

Comment: +1 For mentioning the error cause and give a working example using the right syntax; btw `Unique()` without boolean arguments is the same as 2 times `False` :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you make sure the right worksheet of the right workbook is `Active`:

```
Sub uniqB2H()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("H2").Formula2 = "=Unique(B2:B" & LastRow & ")"
    Range("H2#").Value = Range("H2#").Value
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

1. this approach avoids having to build a VBA array and transfer it to the worksheet
2. in this demo, we assume only a single workbook and a worksheet with data that is already `Active`; thus none of the ranges need to be qualified
3. in this demo `Formula2` is used to deposit a dynamic spill-down formula in a cell
4. in this demo we use `Range("H2#")` which specifies the full spill-down range.

Comment: Correct and would be worth to explain both a spill range reference as well as fully qualifying range references to an apparent new comer :-)

Comment: @T.M.  Valuable comment.  see my **EDIT#1**